# Batch Convert videos in Nested Folders

Tags: video, convert, batch

I used the excellent script from Byte Commander
[How can I convert all video files in nested folders? (batch conversion)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011550/how-can-i-convert-all-video-files-in-nested-folders-batch-conversion/1239219?noredirect=1#comment2087898_1239219)

I have two questions though.

1) Is it possible to completely mirror the source and destination folder ? (scan all sub-folder unders /videos/ and copy the resized videos in the same architecture

/videos/2019/01 => /resized_video/2019/01

/videos/2019/02 => /resized_video/2019/02

/videos/2019/03/anniversary/ => /resized_video/2019/03/anniversary

etc...

2) would it be possible if the destination file exist to skip the conversion (this way I could "synchronise" the original folders and resized folder once a month and not convert again existing videos)

Your help would be very appreciated

Guigeek

Answer (score 0):

For the first question :

```
yes n | cp -i -r videos/ resized_video/
```

It makes an exact mirror of the `videos` in the `resized_video` and if there's a file with the same name , it wouldn't update it.

For the latter :

```
for i in videos/**/*.{mp4,avi,mts,and_whatever_format_you_want}
do
    if [ -f resized_video/$i ] 
    then 
        echo File $i exists. Skip resizing
    else
        do_resizing_and_moving
    fi
done
```

It adds videos from `videos` to `resized_videos` only if there exists no file with the same name.

If anybody has suggestions for improvements , I'm glad to hear.